# Delphi - make the Idhttp run in loop if return page not found error

Tags: delphi, idhttp

How i can make the Idhttp run in loop if return **404 page not found**
the problem is *'GOTO CheckAgain' leads into or out of TRY statement*

```
label
  CheckAgain;
begin  
  CheckAgain:
  try
    idhttp.Get(sURL+WebFile[I], S);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    if AnsiPos('404',E.Message) <> 0 then
    begin
      I := I+1;
      goto CheckAgain;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `while True do if ItsTimeToStop then Break;`, or just `while WantToTryAgain do Something;` P.S. do not parse the exception message; the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception has the `ErrorCode` member.

Comment: @TLama Thanks `while WantToTryAgain do Something` worked great, regarding the exception message `EIdHTTPProtocolException`  i don't understand it

Comment: I meant that the `E` variable in your code context has also the `ErrorCode` member that contains the (already parsed) error code. More about it you might find e.g. in [`this thread`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13950676/960757).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

1. use a `try/except` block in a loop, catching `EIdHTTPProtocolException`  exceptions and checking their `ErrorCode` property for 404:

   ```
   repeat
     try
       IdHttp.Get(sURL+WebFile[I], S);
     except
       on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
       begin
         if E.ErrorCode <> 404 then
           raise;
         Inc(I);
         Continue;
       end;
     end;
     Break;
   until False;
   ```
2. if you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, you can enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, and then your loop can remove the `try/except` and check the `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode` property instead:

   ```
   repeat
     IdHttp.Get(sURL+WebFile[I], S);
     if IdHttp.ResponseCode <> 404 then
       Break;
     Inc(I);
   until False;
   ```
3. use the overloaded version of the `TIdHTTP.Get()` method that has an `AIgnoreReplies` parameter, then you can tell `Get()` to not raise an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception on a 404 response:

   ```
   repeat
     IdHttp.Get(sURL+WebFile[I], S, [404]);
     if IdHttp.ResponseCode <> 404 then
       Break;
     Inc(I);
   until False;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, I'd avoid using `goto`. There are occasions where `goto` should be used, but they are rare and your problem is not suited.

A `while` loop would be more commonly used. You'd be able to build in a maximum retry mechanism too. Perhaps like this:

```
RetryCount := 0;
Succeeded := False;
while RetryCount < MaxRetryCount do
  try
    idhttp.Get(sURL+WebFile[I], S);
    Succeeded := True;
    break; // success, break out of while loop
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      if E.ErrorCode = 404 then
        inc(RetryCount)
      else
        raise;

  end;
```